# json_encode doesn't output in Json format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

So, I'm trying to make a simple web JSON API with data from my MySQL DB (10.0.35-MariaDB) I'm trying to use `json_encode();` to output the information. It succeeds in gathering my data and outputting it only not in a JSON format? 
Here is what's outputted compared to what I'm expecting;
What I have...
[image: My version]
What I dream about having...
[image: What I wan't]
I think the fact that the JSON Formatter Chrome extension doesn't even pick up on my page sorta is a blatant sign that I'm not doing something right...

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'pass', 'db');
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `table`;");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
```

I know that to archive such a beautiful JSON file like steam's it'll require more work so for now, I'm just asking for help on actually outputting in JSON format.

Comment: What makes you think the output wasn't JSON? (Can't really tell from the miniature screenshot nor your description what's supposedly wrong). Is this about any incorrect nesting, too many attributes? Take in mind we also can't see the rest of your code or the database structure.

Comment: Try to test $data using var_dump();

Comment: And if you want a specific layout for your JSON then you will have to process the simple row data you get from the query into whatever array/object structure you want before doing the `json_encode()` on it

Comment: please check if your json is valid or not before claiming. use : https://jsonlint.com/ to validate.

Comment: @mario, here's a full page screenshot for you https://i.imgur.com/FSpnY0Z.png and I have no idea what you would need to see from my database that would help with the issue?

Comment: @Kams that output's this https://i.imgur.com/lmTFzxJ.png

Comment: @new_user ah yea works in there so like deceze mentioned the file is JSON just it's in HTTP format

Comment: So the rushed observation "not in JSON format" is really about the JSON addon not detecting it? Then deceze's answer is spot on. If the MIME type doesn't take hold, do some more testing (`wget -S` or `curl` or at least your browsers dev tools / networking tab to see the response headers). Also whenever something doesn't work: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @mario yea so I wasn't aware that this actually was the correct format as I expected the application then to detect it. Like I mentioned in another comment I haven't got much experience with JSON files so :) thanks for the help though I'll try a few things when I get home.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is being output is perfectly fine JSON. Your browser extension simply doesn't pick up on that fact because you're most likely not denoting the content type in the HTTP `Content-Type` header. Without that, anything is simply plaintext to the browser. Add this before outputting your JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand, I placed header('Content-Type: application/json'); at the top of my php code but still, I get the same result?